# List Reflection

Tags: c#

Имеем переменную `"object value"`, которая указывает на список с одним любым типом. К примеру может ссылаться на такие объекты: `List<string>` или `List<Cat>`. Какое именно из них мы не знаем.
**Вопрос:** как создать список нужного нам типа?
P.S.1: Гуглил - безрезультатно.
P.S.2: Писал вот такой код:

```
 Type valueType = value.GetType();
 Type listType = valueType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
 List<object> instanceList = (List<object>) Activator.CreateInstance(valueType);
```

В результате чего возникает исключение ошибки преобразования типов - `"InvalidCastException"`.

Comment: попробуйте ``var instanceList = Activator.CreateInstance(valueType);`` и посмотрите какой тип у ``instanceList``

Comment: У instanceList тот, что необходим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List<cat> не приводится к List<object>. Рекомендую почитать про ковариантность.

Если Вы работаете в 4-м дотнете и выше, это возможно для IEnumerable<t>, но не более.

Плюс, во всех версиях дотнета, начиная со 2-й, ковариантность поддерживается для массивов.

Кроме того, вместо List<object> Вы можете использовать IList, так как List<t> реализует этот интерфейс. Это оптимальное решение, если Вам нужен список для работы в слабо типизированных сценариях.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю.<br/> Еще маленький вопрос: если я попробую ссылаться на содержимое "value" при помощи интерфейса IList, то получу ошибку компиляции, ведь интерфейс требует класс с его реализацией, а на момент написания программы четко указано, что объект под ссылкой "value" рассматривается как тип object(хоть на самом деле он указывает на объект List<какой-то тип>). Грубо говоря мне нужно написать след. код:
<pre>
<code>
   Type valueType = value.GetType();
   IList<valueType> instanceList = (List<valueType>) value;/\*проблема в том, что здесь будет ошибка\*/
</code>
</pre>

Comment: Не `IList<valuetype>`, а `IList`. Пространство имён `System.Collections`.

Answer (score -1):

В c# есть тип dynamic, который позволяет решить мою проблему. Нужно было просто написать:

```
dynamic instanceList=value;
```

И дальше можно было с ним работать как со списком. Спасибо всем, кто ответил в теме. Скорее всего Я не до конца правильно и внятно описал вопрос, так что извините.